# can't locate popup button with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to use selenium on a webpage but this popup is refraining me to do so.

[image]

note that the popup is only shown when you are not signed in (means you have to run my code so that selenium opens up a new browser window for you which does not have any accounts)

I want to click on the "Not Interested" button through selenium.

I don't want to close the popup every time manually,
is there a way to automate this?

here is my code:

```
# relevant packages & modules

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time

# relevant website
website = 'https://www.daraz.pk/'


# initialize Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
# open website
driver.get(website)

#maximize window
driver.maximize_window()

# waiting for popup
time.sleep(5)

# dealing with pop up

# with xpath

pop_up_deny = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '/html/body/div[9]//div/div/div[3]/button[1]')

pop_up_deny.click()
```

It raised this error:

[image]

My chrome version   : 110.0.5481.178 (Official Build) (64-bit)
My selenium version : ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup element is inside `Shadow-root` element you need to reach to shadow-root first then identify the button `not interested`

```
shadowRoot= driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("div.airship-html-prompt-shadow").shadowRoot''')
shadowRoot.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.airship-btn.airship-btn-deny").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give time to find button. Try-except block provides to show the error and the code still continue to work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    pop_up_deny_xpath = "/html/body/div[9]//div/div/div[3]/button[1]"
    pop_up_deny = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, pop_up_deny_xpath)))
    pop_up_deny.click()
except Exception as e:
    print('Button does not exist', e)
```